# Excel - How to map XML cells and add a space in between cells

Tags: excel, import, spreadsheet

I have an Excel Spreadsheet that I am trying to map the X and Y Values and add a blank cell in between.

My current setup is:

```
<Override>
    <Area>
        <Poly>
            <Point x="10590.0" y="14850.0" />
            <Point x="11000.0" y="15120.0" />
            <Point x="11020.0" y="15100.0" />
            <Point x="10590.0" y="14810.0" />
        </Poly>
    </Area>
    <Area>
        <Poly>
            <Point x="11000.0" y="15120.0" />
            <Point x="11030.0" y="15140.0" />
            <Point x="11045.0" y="15120.0" />
            <Point x="11020.0" y="15100.0" />
        </Poly>
    </Area>
```

And I want Excel, when I Import it, to do this:

```
      X   |   Y
    10590 | 14850
    11000 | 15120
    11020 | 14810
    10590 | 14810
    *This is a blank cell area*
    11000 | 15120
    11030 | 15140
    11045 | 15120
    11020 | 15100
    *Space between Poly Data, I need Spaces*
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What happens if you import our current setup?

Comment: Tried Using XML Source to Map the Elements, and that gives me the values in my question but without the spaces between cells.

Comment: All the Values together, X and Y in their column

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453203/preserve-empty-cells-when-saving-excel-as-xml

Comment: Not what I am looking for, I want to have an empty space when I import the data. I just want a space separating the data between areas